# Passing a class through a signal/slot setup in Qt

Tags: qt, signals, parameter-passing, signals-slots

I'm trying to get the information of several of a class' member variables on the receiving end of a slot/signal setup, so I'd like to pass the entire class through. Unfortunately, after the class has been passed, the member variables seem to be empty. Here's some code snippets:

This sets up the signal to pass the class

```
signals:
    void selected(const ControlIcon *controlIcon);
```

this is the slot/signal connection

```
connect(controllerList->serialController, SIGNAL(selected(const ControlIcon*)),
        infoView, SLOT(serialControllerSelected(const ControlIcon*)));
```

I emit the signal from within the class to be passed

```
emit selected(this);
```

Here's the code to call on the class' member data

```
QLabel *ASCIIStringHolder = new QLabel;
ASCIIStringHolder->setText(controlIcon->m_ASCIIString);
```

Nothing shows up in the label, and when I set a breakpoint, I can see that there's nothing inside `m_ASCIIString`.

I looked to make sure that it was being assigned some text in the first place, and that's not the problem. I also tried the signal/slot setup with and without `const`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set the breakpoint inside of the `serialControllerSelected()` slot? There is something strange here; is `serialController` a `ControlIcon*`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that. SerialController is a child class of ControlIcon, so yes, it is. Also, the signal is sent and received just fine (breakpoints within the slot are reached), so the error is not there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The signal can't be declared to be passing a class and then actually pass the child of that class. I changed the signal, slot, and connect() to be SerialController (the child of ControllerIcon), and everything worked fine.

Comment: This is not true in general case. If you were passing values, it would be another story, but you just pass an address. I've just tested it with a dummy example and it works for me. Does SerialController use multiple inheritance, by any chance? Could be something about pointers realignment, although it beats me why it could cause any problems.

Comment: SerialController only inherits from ControlIcon. Did you make sure that some data contained by the dummy class was passed through? I was able to get the program to compile and run fine, but no data was passed (an empty ControlIcon was created in the slot).

Comment: did the datamenmber you where checking exist in the baseclass of the serialcontroller?

Answer (score 6):

Qt signal/slot mechanism needs metainformation about your custom types, to be able to send them in emitted signals.
To achieve that, register your type with `qRegisterMetaType<MyDataType>("MyDataType");`

Consult [official QMetaType documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/stable/qmetatype.html#details) for more information about this.

Comment: This is only true when passing by value and using a queued connection or an auto connection with different threads. The OP uses pointers so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: when I use the command, I get this error: 'QLabel::Qlabel(const QLabel&)' is private. ControlIcon and SerialController both inherit from QLabel. Any ideas?

Comment: @CoutPotato, to register a meta type, it must have a copy constructor. The compiler tries to generate default ones, but fails due to QLabel's copy constructor being private (this is done intentionally to disable copying). But as I've said, you only need it when you pass by value (which is a bad idea for QWidgets anyway) _and_ the connection is queued which is only useful in multi-threaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

First, since you are using an auto connection, do both sender and receiver live in the same thread? If not, it could happen that the call is queued and when it arrives, the data in the sender was already modified. You could try to use a direct connection just to make sure this isn't the problem.

Second, just for the fun of it, did you try to access the sender by using `qobject_cast<ControlIcon*>(sender())` within the slot? This is how it is usually done if the signal doesn't pass this as an argument. Like this:

```
QLabel *ASCIIStringHolder = new QLabel;
// this is instead of the argument to the slot:
ControlIcon *controlIcon = qobject_cast<ControlIcon*>(sender());
ASCIIStringHolder->setText(controlIcon->m_ASCIIString);
```

Comment: I only have one thread, so they are definitely in the same one. I'm not sure exactly where you're saying to put the qobject_cast thing, but I'll try a few ways and report back.

Comment: @CoutPotato, `sender()`, when called from a slot, returns a pointer to the object that generated the signal due to which the slot was called. So you can just have a slot with no arguments and still can access the sender, but you need to cast it to the actual type to use it, obviously.

Comment: @CoutPotato, see my edit for example code. However, if your application is single-threaded and you do `emit selected(this);`, there shouldn't be any difference in the behavior. It looks like you have a bug somewhere else, maybe memory corruption or something along these lines. There is nothing wrong with the code snippets you posted.

Comment: No luck, the signal was sent and received, but the ControlIcon's members were all still empty. EDIT: hadn't read new comments, I'll try again in a few minutes.